# modeling language evolution with math, is it possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I know that math can be used to create simple models for everything in the physical world, with some limitations of course, but I am particularly interested in extra-physical realm of linguistics.  Would linear algebra or some related fiend be useful in creating a model of language evolution over time?

Say you start with some initial set representing sounds (or roots) and you specify some rules and then you kick start the system.  Could you create something like a "game of life" where a language, or at least some system of words, is formed and evolves over time?  And can you model real languages?

Comment: More likely you will see these kinds of results about abstract phylogenetic trees. Try biological keywords for people with different motivations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is certainly possible and very complicated. One approach is to view the time evolution of a language as a constrained optimization problem, where the constraints represent properties of the language that are either favored or disfavored by speakers. You can then think of a language as an evolving position within this optimization problem, seeking a local maximum.